# firebaseUI dependency not matching with the firebase version 15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-security, firebaseui

firebaseUI dependency not matching with the firebase version 15.0.0  Actually what is happening is that, when I include the firebaseUI dependency , android studio shows some kind of error related to values.xml file. I have linked the picture of error below  and when I remove that line everything works fine , then there is no error.

```
   The code for the entire gradle file is given below:

       apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
       repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            flatDir {
                dirs 'libs'
            }
            maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

        }
            android {
            compileSdkVersion 24
            buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
          defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
                minSdkVersion 16
                targetSdkVersion 24
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                resConfigs "en"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
            compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
            compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
        }apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ERROR:
[image]

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: when I  add that line specific for firebaseUI , it shows some kind of error in values.xml file

Comment: some kind of error? what error?

Comment: ERROR ADDED IN THE POST

Comment: could you post the entire gradle file?

Comment: Done I have posted!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your setup, also firebase UI is still depedning in version **12.0.1** not **15.0.0**. See the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822145/firebaseui-dependency-not-matching-with-the-firebase-version-15-0-0?noredirect=1#49822145) to see which versions match with which firebase ui versions:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
        android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
      defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            resConfigs "en"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I have tried with version 15 but the results were same

Comment: version 12, not 15. Version 3.3.0 of firebase UI depedend on 12 of firebase, https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: I have changed from 15 to 12.0.1, it is still showing the same error

Comment: One last measure was to update your other dependencies, compilesdk, buildtoolsversion and support lib versions. Checkout the edit :) If this doesn't work, please post your project level build gradle file

Comment: @LoveBabbar this gradle is using the 27 appcompat and design, you are using the 24

Answer (score 2):

The [README](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#upgrading-dependencies) at FirebaseUI's github repo is quite clear. You need to explicitly override all the transitive dependencies for each UI library e.g if you are using `firebase-ui-auth` version `3.3.0` but want to use `firebase` version `15.0.0` and `support libaries` version `27.1.1`, it will be be something like below.

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever the Firebase UI dependency you want to use, try adding below two dependencies.
It worked for me, this might work for you as well

```
implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"
```